# Set a default value conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to set a default value of a field based on some conditions.

Right now, a field `room_type` is defaulted to `double`, regardless of the number of people in a room.

Basically I'm aiming for something along the lines of:

```
def set_room_defaults
  if people_in_room.size == 1
    set room_type = "Single"
  elsif people_in_room.size == 2
    set room_type = "Double"
  elsif people_in_room.size == 3
    set room_type = "Triple"
  end
end
```

I've been looking into the `default_value_for` gem, hoping I could do something like:

```
default_value_for :room_type, (call set_room_default)
```

I've read a bit that `after_initialize` might be close to what I'm looking for?

Is something like this possible? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What rails version are you using? If rails 5 checkout [`Attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: _"I am trying to assign a default room_type"_ - Ok. But where do you want to set it? Before saving the record / After initialising an instance? You read about `after_initialize`. So, i guess, you need it after initialising an instance. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Do you really need an additional database field `room_type` if you already have the number of people? What if the number of people changes? Maybe it makes more sense to _compute_ the value instead of persisting it, i.e. just use a method.

Comment: @Stefan I get what you're saying, and that makes sense given the info I provided. But there are actually a few more room_types offered, its just that the majority of the time those are the room_types selected for the respective people_in_room.size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

> after_find and after_initialize callback is triggered for each object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with after_initialize being triggered after new objects are instantiated as well.

You could do something along the lines of:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_room_defaults

  def set_room_defaults
    if people_in_room.size == 1
        set room_type = "Single"
    elsif people_in_room.size == 2
        set room_type = "Double"
    elsif people_in_room.size == 3
        set room_type = "Triple"
    end
  end
end
```

Or you could store the mappings in an `Array`:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  ROOM_TYPES = %w(Single Double Triple).freeze

  after_initialize :set_room_defaults

  def set_room_defaults
    set room_type = ROOM_TYPES[people_in_room.size - 1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! This is helped a ton. Thank you!

Comment: @kkir could you accept the answer as a solution then please? :)